# How to see account id origin when receiving an XCM message. Currently the origin contains the parachain id

Tags: pallet, xcm

Currently to process an XCM message in my own pallet call, I inherit the config of my pallet from frame_system + pallet_xcm to have a representable origin:

```
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_xcm::Config {
    ...
    // We need a specified origin to be used with the functions of the pallet_xcm that take an origin
    type Origin: From<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Origin>
    + Into<Result<XcmOrigin, <Self as Config>::Origin>> + Debug;
    ...
}
```

After this I can call a function like ensure_xcm from the pallet_xcm like this:

```
ensure_xcm(<T as Config>::Origin::from(origin))
```

My problem is that ensure_xcm gets the origin as the parachain id, but I want the account that created the xcm message in the first place, not just the parachain.
It this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a xcm instruction: [DescendOrigin](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#descendorigin)

> Mutate the origin to some interior location.

It will append an account to the `origin` location (which include paraId you mentioned above).

For example, you create a XCM with account `[0u8;32]`:

```
Xcm(vec![
            WithdrawAsset(..),
            BuyExecution {..},
            DescendOrigin(X1(AccountId32 { network: .., id: [0u8;32] })),
            Transact(<your pallet call>)
            ...
        ]);
```

Before your pallet is called by transact, the origin of xcm will be converted by `OriginConverter`, you can find this configuration in [`XcmCExecutorConfig`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/xcm-executor/src/config.rs#L39). And you can customize your converter as needed, such as use the account who created the xcm `[0u8;32]` to sign the origin.

After that, your `ensure_origin` in your call will get the account who created the xcm.

**Note:**

If you use polkadot's [`pallet-xcm.send`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L1069), it will add the `DescendOrigin` instruction for you when you need.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll have to construct a custom XCM that encodes, as a message parameter, the creator of the message. As you've remarked, the message origin is always the parachain ID.

This can be described throughout this XCM format spec: https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format. Here the origin as always a `MultiLocation`, since messages come from specific locations and thus can't be externally-owned accounts as far as I know.

You could implement and send a `Tranasct` XCM in combination with a specific extrinsic that allows you to dispatch and process such XCMs across chain.