# How to ensure the XCM callback is called by the pallet hook in the sending chain?

Tags: xcm

I am sending an XCM `Transact` message in `on_finalize` hook, which calls `on_transact_received` function on the receiving side. I would like to assure that this call was called by the hook (trusted data) and not by some random person. I assume I have to use the [DescendOrigin()](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/how-to-see-account-id-origin-when-receiving-an-xcm-message-currently-the-origin) instruction but I am not sure what to put in on the sending side (a sovereign account? how?) and how to decode it on the receiving side. Can you provide a small code excerpt for both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the sending side, I think you can send your XCM directly **without including `DescendOrigin` instruction**.

   The XCM might be:

   ```
   WithdrawAsset(..),
   BuyExecution(..),
   Transact(..)
   ```
2. And then on the receiving side, you need to make sure the `Origin` which call your function is the sending chain's sovereign account.

Let me explain to you why.

For the first step, in general, without `DescendOrigin` represent the XCM is sent via sudo or governance or your runtime code, which will be your sovereign account on receiving chain, and it is trustworthy. Because [a `DescendOrigin` will be added](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L1078) when an ordinary user send a XCM.

For the second step, maybe you want to know how to calculate the sovereign account, please refer to [how to calculate sovereignAccount for parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/1210)

Comment: Thanks @Guantong, on the receiving side, it does not return on `ensure_signed(origin)` but the XCM call is successful - [function signature](https://pastecode.io/s/bcb1xwf5)
Do you know why? On the sending side I call it with `OriginKind::Native`, I define sovereign account as `pub const SovereignAccount: AccountId =
  sp_runtime::AccountId32::new(hex_literal::hex!["7369626c07d10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]);` however it does not execute this check.

Comment: Maybe you should add logs and debug it.

Comment: I get the `BadSigner` error. Do I have to do something with the `OriginFor` on the receiving side? I am trying to find an example of this.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.34/runtime/parachains/src/hrmp.rs#L475 May be this can be a reference.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, `ensure_parachain` + checking the para ID that matches the sending chain, is already safe enough? If an ordinary user sends, that check would fail, therefore I wouldn't have to decode it? Otherwise the `hrmp_init_open_channel` could be called by any user, is this correct? I don't even have to calculate the sovereign account in this case ...

Comment: Yeah `hrmp_init_open_channel` can't be called by ordinary user, if an ordinary user send the call, `ensure_parachain` would fail.